# Flutter iOS build failed when I run flutter run

Tags: ios, flutter

I have an issue with Flutter. I can't run my app on an iOS simulator and I can't build release for iOS. I get this error when I run app :

```
event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, message: Running "flutter pub get" in Splitti...}
event sent after app closed: {id: 0, progressId: null, finished: true}
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           41,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:28699:25: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
              szBufNeeded = MAX(e2,0)+(i64)precision+(i64)width+15;
                            ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:32750:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'sqlite3_int64' (aka 'long long') to 'VList' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        pIn[0] = nAlloc;
               ~ ^~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:33394:8: warning: "gethostuuid() is disabled." [-W#warnings]
    #      warning "gethostuuid() is disabled."
           ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:34860:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        do{ rc = osWrite(fd, "S", 1); }while( rc<0 && errno==EINTR );
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:33904:21: note: expanded from macro 'osWrite'
    #define osWrite     ((ssize_t(*)(int,const void*,size_t))aSyscall[11].pCurrent)
                        ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:36756:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        got = osPread(id->h, pBuf, cnt, offset);
            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ...
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:94674:28: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
          pSorter->mxPmaSize = MAX(pSorter->mnPmaSize, (int)mxCache);
                               ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:95506:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            iListOff = (u8*)pSorter->list.pList - pSorter->list.aMemory;
                     ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:95517:26: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'sqlite3_int64' (aka 'long long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          pSorter->nMemory = nNew;
                           ~ ^~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:95671:19: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        pIncr->mxSz = MAX(pTask->pSorter->mxKeysize+9,pTask->pSorter->mxPmaSize/2);
                      ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14251:10: note: other definition of 'MAX'
    # define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:96124:21: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
              nReader = MIN(pTask->nPMA - i, SORTER_MAX_MERGE_COUNT);
                        ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:96980:17: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        int nCopy = MIN(nRead, (p->nChunkSize - iChunkOffset));
                    ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:97021:40: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            nChunk = copy.endpoint.iOffset - iOff;
                   ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:97088:22: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
            int iSpace = MIN(nWrite, p->nChunkSize - iChunkOffset);
                         ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:97112:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          p->nSize = iAmt + iOfst;
                   ~ ~~~~~^~~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:97289:10: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MAX' [-Wambiguous-macro]
      return MAX(pVfs->szOsFile, (int)sizeof(MemJournal));
             ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:218:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MAX'
    #define MAX(a, b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    
...
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:220751:40: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
          assert_nc( memcmp(pToken, pTerm, MIN(nToken, nTerm))<=0 );
                                           ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:221593:53: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
            res = fts5Memcmp(&pLeaf->p[iOff], zIdxTerm, MIN(nTerm, nIdxTerm));
                                                        ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:221921:52: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
        iOff += fts5DecodePoslist(pRc, pBuf, &a[iOff], MIN(n-iOff, nPos));
                                                       ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:223056:40: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          pSorter->aIdx[i] = &aBlob[nBlob] - a;
                           ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:226751:19: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            is = zCsr - (unsigned char*)pText;
               ~ ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:226758:21: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
              is = zCsr - (unsigned char*)pText;
                 ~ ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:226808:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
          ie = zCsr - (unsigned char*)pText;
             ~ ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:226812:37: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        rc = xToken(pCtx, 0, aFold, zOut-aFold, is, ie); 
             ~~~~~~                 ~~~~^~~~~~
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:229114:18: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
          int nCmp = MIN(nTerm, pCsr->nLeTerm);
                     ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:14248:10: note: other definition of 'MIN'
    # define MIN(A,B) ((A)<(B)?(A):(B))
             ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:229186:20: warning: ambiguous expansion of macro 'MIN' [-Wambiguous-macro]
            int nCmp = MIN(nTerm, pCsr->nLeTerm);
                       ^
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/sqlite3/sqlite-amalgamation-3320300/sqlite3.c:1074:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/param.h:215:9: note: expanding this definition of 'MIN'
    #define MIN(a, b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            ^
   


...
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/Mime/MultipartFormDataParser.m:32:80: note: previous definition is here
    - (int) numberOfBytesToLeavePendingWithData:(NSData*) data length:(NSUInteger) length encoding:(int) encoding;
                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:54:58: warning: sending 'HTTPServer *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate> _Nullable'
                    asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:serverQueue];
                                                                           ^~~~
    In module 'CocoaAsyncSocket' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:2:
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/CocoaAsyncSocket/Source/GCD/GCDAsyncSocket.h:90:71: note: passing argument to parameter 'aDelegate' here
    - (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(nullable id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>)aDelegate delegateQueue:(nullable dispatch_queue_t)dq;
                                                                          ^
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:162:3: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    documentRoot = valueCopy;
                    ^
                    self->
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:189:3: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    connectionClass = value;
                    ^
                    self->
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/KTVCocoaHTTPServer/Classes/HTTPServer.m:212:3: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    interface = valueCopy;
                    ^
                    self->
...    

/Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessagingExtensionHelper.h:34:1: note: annotate 'populateNotificationContent:withContentHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
    - (void)populateNotificationContent:(UNMutableNotificationContent *)content
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/splitti1/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:195:43: error: expected a type
    - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                              ^
    /Users/splitti1/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:302:53: error: nullability specifier 'nonnull' conflicts with existing specifier 'nullable'
        didReceiveRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken {
    
                                                  ^
    In module 'UserNotifications' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessagingExtensionHelper.h:19:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/Headers/UNNotificationContent.h:16:12: note: 'UNNotificationContent' has been marked as being introduced in iOS 10.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
    @interface UNNotificationContent : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding>
               ^
    While building module 'FirebaseMessaging' imported from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:66:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h:18:
    /Users/splitti1/Projects/Splitti/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Public/FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessagingExtensionHelper.h:34:1: note: annotate 'populateNotificationContent:withContentHandler:' with an availability attribute to silence this warning
    - (void)populateNotificationContent:(UNMutableNotificationContent *)content
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'cached_video_player' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 

...

    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  contacts_service: ^0.3.10
  rxdart: any
  permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  animated_floatactionbuttons: ^0.1.0
  solid_bottom_sheet: ^0.1.9
  share: ^0.6.4
  http: ^0.12.1
  device_info: ^0.4.2+2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  image_picker: ^0.6.6+1
  #^6.0.13
  firebase_messaging:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  url_launcher: ^5.4.7
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0
  bot_toast: ^3.0.0
  percent_indicator: "^2.1.5"
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: #^2.0.0
  moor: ^3.4.0 # use the latest version
  #moor_ffi: ^0.5.0
  sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.3.0
  path_provider:
  path:
  flutter_luban: ^0.1.11
  app_settings: ^4.0.4
  number_display:
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  intl: any
  uuid: ^2.2.2
  dotted_border: ^1.0.7
  #sms: ^0.2.4
  #tutorial_coach_mark: ^0.5.2
  cached_network_image:
  material_design_icons_flutter:
  cached_video_player:
  story_view:
  photo_view:
  uni_links:
  flutter_credit_card:
  cool_alert:
  country_code_picker:
  flutter_country:
  #card_scanner:

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  moor_generator: # use the latest version
  build_runner:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.0"
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.2.9

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/images/iconsround.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path_ios: "assets/images/logo_ios2.jpg"
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the c
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

This is flutter doctor -v command

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H1217 darwin-x64,
    locale fr-CD)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/splitti1/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (8 months ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/splitti1/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[!] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

 
[✓] Connected device (1 available)            
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 4C0D6598-33D1-46B3-8871-9EEC509C33F4 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
```

I use flutter 1.22.5 version.
How can I solve this issue, I have tried all the solutions but so far my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete Podfile.lock
2. run pod install in iOS directory
3. Flutter clean && flutter run

You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

use pod install in ios directory

Answer (score 0):

First of all, My environment is windows 7 and laptop. But, you can think. In my opinion, you have to follow 'flutter doctor'

First, He recommended android licenses. you have to solve it.
By use git bash here, command 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' and
follow them.

If it isn't clear, it is another problem. maybe need to install java 8 on the net and Java development kit on the visual studio extensions and correct Path for JDK.

Second,
✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

- on Android studio, you can find plugins. Search dart and install it. and then find flutter and install it.

if you solved all, all close them, re run android adv manager. and delete all device and remake device. you can run emulator.
keep this emulator and close android studio, and open visual studio.
it is better than android studio for flutter.
If you open visual studio, you can use start debugging. you can see your project on emulator at visual studio like android emulator

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing. Please read the question carefully before answering. The Original Post was asking for something related to IOS and Xcode, not something remotely about the Windows environment or Android. Thank you. :)